# Python get s3 file from download link

Tags: python, file, amazon-s3, download-manager

I have a download link like such:

```
url = https://api.some.service:443/v2/encodedreport/13402/custom/7378/2019/05/30/MTA4Nzk2X1RlYWRzJTIwLSUyMERTVyUyMFJlcG9ydF8yMDE5MDUzMDEzMDU1OC54bHN4
```

When i click on the link or open in a browser it starts the download manager and I can click download to download the (xlsx) file. I'd like to automate this download with python.

I tried using requests:

```
>>> r = requests.get(url)
# long string of binary looking data
>>> r.content
b'PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x08\x08\x08\x00\xbdh\xbeN\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0b\x00\x00\x00_rels/.rels\xad\x92MK\x031\x10\x86\xffJ\x98{7\xdb*"\xd2\xb4\x17\x11z\x13\xa9?`Lf?\xd8M&$S]\xff\xbdA\x0f\xda\xb2\x85\n=\x0e3\xef\xf3>\x87Yo\'?\xaawJ\xb9\xe7``Y\xd5\xa0(Xv}h\r\xbc\xee\x9f\x16\xf7\xa0\xb2`p8r \x03\x81a\xbbY\xbf\xd0\x8...
# seems to involve aws s3
>>> r.headers
{'x-amz-id-2': 'lI0SDLtoaJHSJF4Ekn6uq81aFNn...f5rGbREk3iEKzZSq2Hyr1ykFwOYq2kpw=', 'x-amz-request-id': 'C01C13...C19B3C', 'Date': 'Mon, 01 Jul 2019 13:59:45 GMT', 'Last-Modified': 'Thu, 30 May 2019 13:05:59 GMT', 'x-amz-expiration': 'expiry-date="Sun, 30 May 2021 00:00:00 GMT", rule-id="outdated-reports-after-2years"', 'ETag': '"3924c5ba183c...88bf658db37dc"', 'x-amz-server-side-encryption': 'AES256', 'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes', 'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream', 'Content-Length': '8261', 'Server': 'AmazonS3'}
```

How can i download this file programmatically?

Comment: I believe you have already downloaded this file. `r.content` shows this file. All you need is just storing it like `with open("whatever.xlsx", "w") as f: \n f.write(r.content)`.

Comment: lmao answer is right in front of my face. It's an excel file so that's just what it looks like. Feel free to answer and I'll mark it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
open('YOUR_NAME', 'wb').write(r.content)
```

Comment: `allow_redirects=True` - very clean! But does this construct close the file?